# Align divs horizontally using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend

I have the following code

```
<div id="profile" >
  <div class"row">
  <div>
</div>
<div id="principal">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

I need one div to be at the left and the other div to the right using Bootstrap 3.1.1 or css without forgetting responsive design.
Thanks.

Comment: third line is `</div>` , right?

Comment: Exactly Afghanistan!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you!

```
<div id="profile" class="span4"> // class="column-sm-4"
  <div class"row">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="principal" class="span8"> // class="column-sm-8">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I want to has the same height, because if a div has more rows that other it has more height

Comment: user `overflow:scroll;` for your div.

Comment: it only adds a scroll to div, I want to divs have the same height

Comment: then use the same fixed height for them

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what I wanted :)